# Show predefined range options and calendar at the same time (daterangepicker.js)

Tags: daterangepicker

Using the JS [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) library I would like to show a list of predefined ranges AND a calendar picker at the same time. Currently, the intended behaviour is to only show the calendar when the "Custom range" option is selected, as stated on [this related ticket on their repo](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/issues/1307). However, I find 'hard' to select some random single day in the past like this.

For example, imagine I have the following predefined ranges: "Today", "Yesterday", "This week" and "Custom range". In case I let my users pick 4 days in the past, they would need to:

1. Open the widget
2. Select "Custom range"
3. Select four days in the past as the starting range
4. Select four days in the past again as the ending range

These are 4 clicks for just picking a single date while giving the chance of predefined ranges! Why don't they show a simple calendar picker before clicking on "Custom range" to let users select a single date with just 1 click? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have same functionality in my app, where a user can select a predefined range (e.g last 7 days, last month, last 3 months, last 6 months etc). What I have done is added a drop down with these options and whenever user clicks "Custom range" it opens date range picker.

Now whether we can display these in date range picker, some may argue that these ranges may vary a lot and setting these & populating in drop down via config seems out of scope for date range picker. But you may customize the lib to implement if you want.

Comment: Tnx for answering! But "customise the lib yourself to implement what you want" is a bit far from a proper answer... I was looking for a config I didn't know, a quick workaround, even a dirty trick to make it work for now (or at least some specific direction). Sadly, it looks like there is no easy way...